# strip all unnecessary spaces in a php string

Tags: php, str-replace

I want to strip all spaces that are **not between two letters**:

```
$string = "              bah    bah    bah bah  ";
$string = str_replace("/w /w", "+", $string);
// what goes here? to get this:
$string = "bah+bah+bah+bah";
```

The idea is that i want to get rid of all unnecessary spaces(not only at the beginning and end). This is not for a link but for a search box that on submit will be exploded so the + can even be a = or anything basically

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$string = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $string);
```

Comment: yep that too, you can put it directly inside the `preg_replace()`

Comment: @OhMrBigshot: Cheers. Thought I was having a stroke.

Answer (score 3):

If your ultimate goal is to *explode* a search string (i.e. into an array of terms) I suggest condensing all steps into one using [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/preg_split)

```
$search_terms = preg_split('/\s+/', $search_string);
print_r($search_terms);
```